# printf spits out garbage even though the char array is null terminated and checked

Tags: c, arrays, char, nul

I have an assignment in which we're to make a Caesar (rot) cipher, but without using array notation (a[b]). It seems like it should work, but it spews out random garbage past the end of the string, even though a check is performed on lines 41 and 51

```
/* lab 08 */
/* exercise for loops and pointers */
/* assume that plain text which needs to be encrypted has
 * only capital letters */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int Caesar_encrypt(char *p, char *s, int enckey);
int Caesar_decrypt(char *p, char *s, int enckey);

int main(void){
    char A[]="THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG";
    char B[50], /* stores encrypted output string   */
    C[50];  /* stores decrypted output using string B as source */
    int enckey,
    statuse, statusd; /* they store return values from the functions */

    printf("Plaintext for encryption is : %s \n", A);

    printf("Input numerical key for Caesar's cypher : ");
    scanf("%d", &enckey );  // COMPLETE THIS

    putchar('\n');
    printf("You entered encryption key %d \n", enckey);
    /* encrypt by Caesar's cypher */
    statuse= Caesar_encrypt(A, B, enckey);

    printf("Ciphertext is : %s \n", B);

    /* decrypt by Caesar's cypher */
    statusd = Caesar_decrypt(B, C, enckey);
    printf("Decrypted text is: %s \n", C);
    exit (0);
}

int Caesar_encrypt(char *p, char *s, int enckey) {  // COMPLETE THE INPUT PARAMETERS
    enckey %= 26;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(p+i); i++) {
        if (*(p+i) != ' ') *(s+i) = (*(p+i) - 'A' + enckey) % 26 + 'A';
        else *(s+i) = ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}

int Caesar_decrypt(char *p, char *s, int enckey) {  // COMPLETE THE INPUT PARAMETERS
    enckey %= 26;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(p+i); i++) {
        if (*(p+i) != ' ') *(s+i) = (*(p+i) - 'A' + 26 - enckey) % 26 + 'A';
        else  *(s+i) = ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Plaintext for encryption is : THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG 
Input numerical key for Caesar's cypher : 1

You entered encryption key 1 
Ciphertext is : UIF RVJDL CSPXO GPY KVNQT PWFS UIF MBAZ EPH8???THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG 
Decrypted text is: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG47;Q9=@SGD PTHBJ AQNVM ENW ITLOR NUDQ SGD KZYX CNF8???THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Comment: Your `Caesar_decrypt` and `Caesar_encrypt` functions don't zero-terminate the string when they're done. So `printf` doesn't know where to stop printing it.

Comment: relevant: http://favo.s3.amazonaws.com/if-programming-languages-were-essays.jpg

Comment: have you tried debugging the code..........if you had then i think you would have known to terminate the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to proper terminate the strings in both your `Caesar_encrypt()` and `Caesar_decrpyt()` functions.
C strings are terminated with a single **`'\0'` character**, so you can add this line before the `return 0;` at the bottom of the aforementioned function bodies:

```
    .... 

    // Terminate the string, adding a \0
    *(s+i) = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

BTW: I prefer using the *array syntax* `s[i]` to identify single characters in strings, so I'd do `s[i] = 0;`.

---

Moreover, you may want to use `const` to mark the input (read-only) strings in your function signatures (and update function definitions as well):

```
int Caesar_encrypt(const char *p, char *s, int enckey);
int Caesar_decrypt(const char *p, char *s, int enckey);
```

Comment: I don't like it either, but our function prototypes and most other (garage, quite frankly) code is given by the TA

Answer (score 3):

You're not zero-terminating the result strings in the encrypt or decrypt functions.

You need to add `*(p+i) = 0;` or, preferably, `p[i] = 0;` after the loop in the encrypt function, and `s[i] = 0;` after the loop in the decrypt function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s[i] = 0;` in both cases? It seems that `s` is the destination string.

Comment: @Mr.C64: you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your encrypt/decrypt functions do stop encrypting/decpryting when they encounter zero in the *source* array (which is correct), but they don't explicitly zero-terminate the *target* array (which is a problem). Try adding an explicit null termination after the loops.